# How to convert a JS Date (programmatically) into a Google Sheet Serial Number and vice-versa?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So, I have a JS date

```
> new Date()
Mon Aug 05 2019 06:55:46 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time
```

In Google Sheets API, the default dateTime render option is `DateTimeRenderOption.SERIAL_NUMBER`, which as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DateTimeRenderOption#ENUM_VALUES.SERIAL_NUMBER) says

> Instructs date, time, datetime, and duration fields to be output as doubles in "serial number" format, as popularized by Lotus 1-2-3. The whole number portion of the value (left of the decimal) counts the days since December 30th 1899. The fractional portion (right of the decimal) counts the time as a fraction of the day. For example, January 1st 1900 at noon would be 2.5, 2 because it's 2 days after December 30st 1899, and .5 because noon is half a day. February 1st 1900 at 3pm would be 33.625. This correctly treats the year 1900 as not a leap year.

I want to know how to convert the `JS Date` to `SERIAL_NUMBER` using API/library and back from `SERIAL_NUMBER` to `JS Date` object?

Comment: Please let us know how your feature turned out and if our responses were helpful

Comment: @Cat, I will surely try them out this week and post an update. THANK YOU for all the help you folks have put in.

Answer (score 3):

This will get you the serial number. You may or may not want to trim it

```
function createSerialNum() {
    var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var firstDate = new Date(1899, 11, 30);
    var secondDate = new Date();
    console.log(secondDate);
    var secondDateMidnight = new Date(secondDate.getFullYear(), secondDate.getMonth(), secondDate.getDate());
    var diff = secondDate.getTime() - secondDateMidnight.getTime();
    var left = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (oneDay))) - 1;
    var right = diff / oneDay;
    var result = left + right;
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
```

This will turn back it into a date

```
function createDateFromSerial(serialNum){
    serialNum = String(serialNum).split(".");
    var ogDate;
    var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var firstDate = new Date(1899, 11, 30);  
    var days = serialNum[0];
    var ms = serialNum[1] * oneDay;
    ms = String(ms).substring(0, 8);

    firstDate.setDate(days);

    ogDate = new Date(firstDate.getFullYear(), firstDate.getMonth(), firstDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, ms);
    console.log(ogDate);
    return ogDate;
}
```

Comment: This is off by 1 day (instead of March 4 the number returned represents March 3). In the definition of `left`, there's no need for subtracting 1. :)

Answer (score 1):

Before we get to conversions first some notes on the serial number format.

**Serial Format**

As described in the documentation, the serial number has two parts. The integer before the decimal representing the days from December 30th 1899, and the fraction representing the time of day, without a timezone. That is, 0.5 always represents the time 12:00 (Noon), regardless of the user machine or sheet's set timezone, daylight savings, or anything else.

**Time zone:**

The Serial number is without time zone. This means that a cell value of 0 will always be rendered as "12/30/1899 0:00:00", regardless of the sheet's timezone.
The sheet's timezone only affects functions such as NOW() or TODAY(), and changing the timezone will change their numeric output (and not change the numeric output of TIME() functions).

For example:

- Set a cell to the formula =NOW(), then format the cell to render as a number.
- Change the sheet's timezone to a different timezone +6 hours from what it previously was.
- Make a change to the sheet so the NOW() value recalculates.
- Notice that the numeric value will change by about +0.25 to represent 6 hours difference.
- Also note that no other date-time cells change their display from the time zone change.

When getting data via [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get), the default `valueRenderOption` is
`ValueRenderOption.FORMATTED_VALUE`, which means that the default `dateTimeRenderOption` of `DateTimeRenderOption.SERIAL_NUMBER` is ignored.

**Formatting**

A DATE_TIME formatted cell will be in a locale format according to the spreadsheet's locale, not the user machine's locale, e.g. "9/12/2020 8:15:40" or "12.9.2020 8:15:40" if the spreadsheet is set to German.  If all you're doing with the date is displaying it, and you don't care that there may be a locale mismatch, this is ok. Note that it's not ok to use `Date.parse()` on this string, as the value will be inconsistent if the spreadsheet locale is something other than English.

If you change `valueRenderOption` to `ValueRenderOption.UNFORMATTED_VALUE`, we get the `SERIAL_NUMBER` value of dates, which I'll give formulas to below.

**Writing**

To write to the sheet using a JS Date, we don't necessarily need to convert it to lotus serial format. We can write to the cell using a formula:

`` `=DATE(${date.getFullYear()}, ${date.getMonth() + 1}, ${date.getDate()}) + TIME(${date.getHours()}, ${date.getMinutes()}, ${date.getSeconds()})` ``

This will have a formula output of something like: `=DATE(2020, 9, 12) + TIME(9, 15, 41)`
That cell will render as 9/12/2020 9:15:41, regardless of timezone.

In that example the cell was written with the date object's local time. We can write it as the date object's UTC time via:

`` `=DATE(${date.getUTCFullYear()}, ${date.getUTCMonth() + 1}, ${date.getUTCDate()}) + TIME(${date.getUTCHours()}, ${date.getUTCMinutes()}, ${date.getUTCSeconds()})` ``

Which you use depends on your use case.  Using the local time means that if the local time is 3:15, the cell renders within sheets how you'd expect as "3:15".
Using UTC time means that if the local time is 3:15, and your timezone is -600GMT, the cell will display as "9:15", possibly adding confusion.
Using local time can be a problem however if you are finding the difference between two dates. Take the case of daylight savings. If for example you are in America/Chicago timezone with daylight savings time ending 2am Nov 1, 2020, then the local time difference between 2am and 1am is 2 hours.

`(new Date(2020, 10, 1, 2)) - (new Date(2020, 10, 1, 1)) // 7200000 (2 hours) (note JS month is 0-indexed)`

But in Sheets, there is no daylight savings time, so subtracting those two dates will be 1 hour, regardless of the spreadsheet's set timezone.

So we have a few options:

1. Consider the sheet date_time values as UTC times.
   Pros: Times are unambiguous. Apps can render the time stamp in the user's timezone and save as UTC.
   Cons: Editing the sheet directly can be confusing, as you'd need to convert local times to UTC by hand. Would not work with NOW() / TODAY() functions.
2. Consider the sheet values to have no time zone.
   Pros: Times work with NOW() and TODAY() methods. When editing the sheet directly, times are always entered as the user's local time.
   Cons: Timezone information is lost. When calculating the difference between times, daylight savings time changes can cause calculation to be off by an hour.
3. Consider the sheet values to be relative to the time zone in which the sheet is set.
   Pros: Times are unambiguous. Times work with NOW() and TODAY() methods.
   Cons: Sheet time zones are always standard time, so editing the sheet directly has the same problems as #1. Converting between sheet's standard time and user's local time is difficult and requires external libraries.

No matter which method we choose, we'll start with the same formulae.

**Finally, the Code**

(Note that this is very similar to Jeremy Ring's answer, except this will handle DST changes)

```
/**
 * Converts a Lotus serial format to a JS UTC date.
 * @param serial {number}
 * @return {Date}
 */
function serialToDateUTC(serial) {
  const intPart = Math.floor(serial);
  const fracPart = serial - intPart;
  const time = Math.round(fracPart * DAY_TO_MS);
  const date = new Date(Date.UTC(1899, 11, 30 + intPart) + time);
  return date;
}

/**
 * Converts a JS Date to Lotus serial format.
 * @param date {Date}
 * @return {number}
 */
function utcDateToSerial(date) {
  const dateSansTime = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate()));
  const intPart = Math.round((dateSansTime.getTime() - Date.UTC(1899, 11, 30)) / DAY_TO_MS);
  const fracPart = (date.getTime() - dateSansTime.getTime()) / DAY_TO_MS;
  return intPart + fracPart;
}
```

To display the UTC date, use `Date.toUTCString` (Or `Intl.DateTimeFormat` with the timeZone set). Example:

`console.log(serialToDateUTC(44086.344212963).toUTCString()); // 9/12/2020 8:15:40`

(Option 1)
If we wish to store in sheets as UTC, and display to the user in local time, we read/write to sheets with these UTC conversions, but then display locally via `Date.toLocaleString` or `Intl.DateTimeFormat`
Note that this option it may be confusing when editing the time directly within the Google document; the times will need to be entered in the UTC timezone.

(Option 2)
If we're ignoring time zone, this means we're considering the date/time value from sheets to always be local to the user, regardless of their timezone.
For this, if we have a Date with local time 4:24, we want to store 4:24 in sheets (using a formula this is simply `=TIME(4, 24, 0)`.
To do this, we can use the same methods posted earlier, but coerce/pretend that the local time is a UTC time.  E.g.

`const timestamp = new Date(); new Date(Date.UTC(timestamp.getFullHours(), timestamp.getMonth(), timestamp.getDate(), timestamp.getHours(), timestamp.getMinutes(), timestamp.getSeconds()));`

This will make time differences unstable -- Consider a timesheet application where you took a start time and an end time via Date.now() or new Date(), and had a duration cell with the formula end time minus start time. Coercing this to standard time may then lose or gain an hour in the difference if we straddle the time change.

(Option 3)
Treating all times local to the Sheet's timezone.
This requires us to get two pieces of information. The cell data, and the sheet's timezone. JavaScript natively has no way to create a Date in another timezone, nor does it have a way to get a timezone offset from an arbitrary timezone. To do this we'll need an external library such as [countries-and-timezones](https://github.com/manuelmhtr/countries-and-timezones).
Get the timezone with the Google files.get api, then get the dstOffset (not the utc offset) from the countries-and-timezones lookup. Use that offset to adjust the sheet's timezone from the local timezone's `Date.getTimezoneOffset()`. Yep, kinda gnarly.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this for Google Sheet API. Works fine for me.

```
// Hour format: HH:MM
// Date format: YYYY-MM-DD
function serialDate(hour, date) {

  let leftDate = date;
  leftDate = new Date(leftDate);
  leftDate = leftDate.getTime();

  let serialNumberReference = (new Date('1899-12-30')).getTime();

  leftDate = (leftDate - serialNumberReference) / (3600 * 24 * 1000);

  let rightDate = date;
  rightDate = (new Date(rightDate + ' ' + hour)).getTime() - (new Date(rightDate + ' 00:00').getTime());
  rightDate = rightDate / (3600 * 24 * 1000);

  return leftDate + rightDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(The algorithm for this is very similar to the one for converting between Celsius and Fahrenheit, which you may be vaguely familiar with.)

**There are three main differences between the scale used for JavaScript dates and the one you describe for Google Sheets:**
1) JS dates are millisecond-based, whereas Google Sheets dates are day-based,
2) JS dates take 1-Jan-1970 (at 12:00:00 AM UTC) to equal zero, while Google Sheets dates use 30-Dec-1900 for this purpose, and
3) The `Date` (and `Time`) constructor in Google Sheets expects its input's timezone to match UTC, whereas JavaScript's Date constructor uses the timezone of whatever location the script runs in.

To convert between the two formats -- as well adjusting for timezone handling -- **we need to "stretch" the scale** (using multiplication/division) to get from days to milliseconds, **and we also need to "shift" the scale** (using addition / subtraction) to account for the different interpretations of 'zero'.

**This shows in detail how it can be done:**
(Note that this script has not been tested using Google Sheets, with the exception of the one example value shown here.)

```js
// Defines constants in milliseconds (JavaScript's unit for dates)
const MS_PER_MINUTE        = 60000; // Assumes no leap year adjustment in this minute
const MS_PER_DAY           = 86400000; // Assumes no leap year adjustment in this day
const MS_PER_70YEARS_2DAYS = 2209161599801; // Diff between gSheets' & unix's "zero"

// Defines functions to build JS UTC Date objects
/* (The first function makes a preliminary Date object, calculates the difference 
between the user's timezone and UTC, and use this to make the final Date object) */
function newUTCDateFromComponents(YYYY, MM, DD = 1, hh = 0, mm = 0, ss = 0){
  // Takes 2 to 6 arguments (the components of a Date), returns a UTC Date object
  const date = new Date(YYYY, MM, DD, hh, mm, ss);
  const offsetMillisecs = date.getTimezoneOffset() * MS_PER_MINUTE;
  return new Date(date.getTime() - offsetMillisecs);
}
function newUTCDateFromTimestamp(timestamp){
  // Takes a timestamp, returns a UTC Date object
  const date = new Date(timestamp);
  return date;    
}

// Defines functions to convert between JavaScript timestamps and gSheets dates
function gsheetsDateToJsTimestamp(days){
  const jsTimestamp = (days * MS_PER_DAY) - MS_PER_70YEARS_2DAYS;
  return jsTimestamp;
}
function jsUTCTimestampToGsheetsDate(millisecs){
  let days = (millisecs + MS_PER_70YEARS_2DAYS) / MS_PER_DAY;
  days = Math.ceil(days * 100000) / 100000; // Rounds the result up to 5 digits
  return days;
}

//
// Examples
//
  // JS to gSheets
  const jsUTCDateSource = newUTCDateFromComponents(2019, 0, 1, 16, 20); // 2019-JAN-01, 4:20PM
  const jsUTCDateStringSource = jsUTCDateSource.toUTCString();
  const jsUTCMillisecSource = jsUTCDateSource.getTime();
  const gsheetsDateResult = jsUTCTimestampToGsheetsDate(jsUTCMillisecSource);
  console.log(`${jsUTCDateStringSource}
from JS (milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 began): ${jsUTCMillisecSource}
to Google Sheets (days since Dec 30, 1899 began): ${gsheetsDateResult}`);
  console.log(`-----------`);

  // gSheets to JS
  const gsheetsDateSource = 43466.68056; // 2019-JAN-01, 4:20PM
  const jsMillisecsResult = gsheetsDateToJsTimestamp(gsheetsDateSource);
  const jsUTCDateResult = newUTCDateFromTimestamp(jsMillisecsResult);
  const jsUTCMillisecsResult = jsUTCDateResult.getTime();
  const jsUTCDateStringResult = jsUTCDateResult.toUTCString();
  console.log(`from Google Sheets: ${gsheetsDateSource}
to JS: ${jsUTCMillisecsResult} // off by a fraction of a second (see below)
human-readable string: ${jsUTCDateStringResult}`);
  console.log(`NOTE: The result is off by a fraction of a second due to rounding 
  but evaluates to the same human-readable string.`);
```

Answer (score -1):

Date to Serial Number: `(date.getTime() - new Date(1899, 11, 30).getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

Serial Number to Date: `new Date(serialNumber * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + new Date(1899, 11, 30).getTime())`